# Accessing Silverlight Text Property in Loaded Event

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am subscribed to the Loaded event of a Silverlight TextBox. I would like to access the Text property in this event. It works properly when I directly set the text, but when I am binding the Text property it is always empty. Is there way to do this without subscribing to the LayoutUpdated event instead?

Comment: How about using TextChanged event instead?

Comment: Yep, that worked. You should enter as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try using [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property instead. :)